# Column names as variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to pass column name as a parameter. Here I have written a query to select the column 'user_id' from table users, but it returns user_id as text.

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT $1 FROM users 
WHERE name=''name''')
USING 'user_id';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You cannot pass a column name as a parameter.  You need to change the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use Dynamic SQL to get this result? something like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT '|| get_columns()|| ' FROM table_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html)...

> Note that parameter symbols can only be used for data values — if you
>   want to use dynamically determined table or column names, you must
>   insert them into the command string textually. For example, if the
>   preceding query needed to be done against a dynamically selected table...

So you need something like this

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT '
    || quote_ident(p_column)
    || ' FROM users '
    || ' WHERE name = $1'
   INTO v_result
   USING name;
```

`p_column` is the column name received as a parameter in your function.
`v_result` is a variable for storing the result. This `INTO` part can be discarded if you don't care about the result.
`name` is the value supplied to the where condition. Must be somewhere in your function or get as a parameter too.